# Can't reset password with Laravel on local

Tags: laravel, authentication

`resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

`/password/reset`

```
# resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.email') }}">
  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

  <button type="submit">
    Send Reset Link
  </button>
</form>
```

After a post to `/password/reset`, I got a `TokenMismatchException` error:

[image: Page showing default laravel 5.4 TokenMismatchException]

Route:

```
$ php artisan route:list | grep password
| account.local.mysite.com | POST                           | password/email                                  | password.email                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,ip,guest                  |
| account.local.mysite.com | POST                           | password/reset                                  |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,ip,guest                  |
| account.local.mysite.com | GET|HEAD                       | password/reset                                  | password.request                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,ip,guest                  |
| account.local.mysite.com | GET|HEAD                       | password/reset/{token}                          | password.reset                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,ip,guest
```

.env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:asffwl8j+2xW+LOzTIPcsO0XsMdwjeijKo6ktLyrpI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_SCHEME=http
```

Added `.env` file of first 5 lines. It contains `APP_KEY`, but why can't find under `php artisan tinker`?

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you set `APP_KEY` using `php artisan key:g`? Have you made any changes to `Http/kernel.php`?

Comment: @Kyslik  I created a `.env` file. There is an `APP_KEY` in it. When I check `echo $APP_KEY` returned null. How to load `.env` file to environment variables?

Comment: .env is loaded at runtime, you can always check env variables inside a tinker: `$ art tinker \n
Psy Shell v0.9.8 (PHP 7.1.14 — cli) by Justin Hileman \n
>>> env('APP_KEY') \n
=> "base64:NpYQjnFNt6xM3BKGj3ue9ax7jpqjxbDBxPSrvLWdEHE="`. From within the Laravel you need to use `echo config('APP_KEY');`

Comment: I have `.env` file. When I check `env('APP_KEY')` under `tinker`, got `null`. Why?

Comment: Paste first 5 lines of .env file in the question body as an edit.

Comment: @Kyslik Added the content.

Comment: Do `php artisan config:clear` and check again `env('APP_KEY')` in the tinker.

Comment: This time, the key value has been found. But when I tried the reset feature again, got the same error again.

Comment: Yea, now you need to clear everything and try again, so do `php artisan clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan auth:clear-resets`, `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: I tried that. But unfortunately, the same result:(

Comment: Try deleting your session in the browser or use incognito feature of the browser.

Comment: Okay, it works now! Thank you very much for the right solution!

Comment: Delete the question, or write an answer yourself. Good Luck!

Comment: I wrote an answer myself below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clear these options and clear browser cache, it works.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan auth:clear-resets
php artisan view:clear
```